# node module raml2html returning empty braces

Tags: html, node-modules, raml

I am using raml2http node package to convert my raml document to html document.

Installed raml2http gloabally using

```
npm install -g raml2html
```

Command to convert raml to html

```
raml2html -i [input file path] -o [output file path]
```

result - Empty braces instead of an html document.

```
{}
```

Am i doing anything wrong in this ?

Comment: Try this "npm install raml2html@3.0.1 -g"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to raml2html [docs](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html#raml-to-html) , raml2html 4 and higher only support RAML 1.0 files . I had installed raml2html 4 and was using it on raml 0.8 file , hence got the empty braces . Degrading the raml2html version solved the issue.

Comment: The error has been improved with 4.1.1 so you no longer get those empty braces :)

Comment: npm install raml2html@3.0.1 -g